# How can I allow anyone to read/write files on a USB stick?

Tags: usb, permissions, ext4

I've got a USB stick which is only used on Ubuntu machines, so is formatted ext4.
The users on my machines have various user IDs, which means that a file created by a user on one won't necessarily be readable by a user on another, and directories wont necessarily be writable by the same token.

The only way I've currently found around this is to run `sudo chmod -R 777 /media/Username/Usbstick` before unmounting, each time I create a new file or directory.  Is there a better way to do this, which will ensure anything put on removable devices is globally read/writable by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a fstab entry for the USB drive on each of the machines and set the uid and gid to 1000 with the desired umask. To get the UUID of the device

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null
```

Hopefully you will be able to identify your USB device ID from here. Now create a directory where the USB should be mounted.

```
sudo mkdir /meda/USBDrive
```

Now, you can create an fstab entry regarding the drive.

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

Use the editor of your choice and append an entry that looks something like the following:

```
UUID=ABCDEFGHIJKLKLMNOP /media/USBDrive ext4 defaults,auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002 0 0
```

You can set the umask as desired. Umask is what determines the read write permissions and  is a 3 digit number with each of the digits between 0 and 7, and is subtracted from 777 to get the permissions. Setting umask=000 will give everyone the permission to read, write and execute all files. More information here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way of doing this more generally for stuff that gets mounted under /media, so each device doesn't have to be manually set up?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know of a reliable way of doing this in general. However this is a good question, I'll keep looking and post back.